# All commands are not working on mac os x lion

Tags: shell, classpath, osx-lion

I am facing a problem, i can't run even a single command on my mac osx lion terminal, even "ls" command, when i print $PATH variable, found

```
My-Mac:/ Mac$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/git/bin
```

Please help me if you have guys have any solution for that.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably ask this question on superuser.stackexchange.com (for "power user"-type questions; instead of here, which is meant for programming questions).

But I'll help you out a little bit: beyond the `.tcshrc` file you should also have for your home directory, also check to see if you have any files at `/usr/share/tcsh/examples`.  That is where the "global" tcsh settings (including PATH) should be found.

If you don't have a `.tcshrc` file... create one in TextEdit and add something like:

```
set path = (                                                    \
                ~/bin                                           \
                /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin                    \
                /usr/local/sbin /usr/sbin /sbin                 \
           )
```

to it.

Oh yeah, lastly... I'm assuming you're using tcsh since that's the usual Macintosh shell.  You can make sure by typing in `echo $SHELL` at the command line.

Comment: there is no tcsh dirctory 

`My-Mac:/ Mac$ cd /usr/share/tcsh/examples
-bash: cd: /usr/share/tcsh/examples: No such file or directory`

Comment: Well then create a .tcshrc file and add that above command to it.  Good luck!

Comment: got the solution :)

there is .bash_profile file in my home dir, i deleted that :) now its running fine